# update with select and case statement in mysql

Tags: mysql

can anyone help me with this query what is going wrong in this query.

**Query**

```
update vcd_deals
set del_date='2015-09-17'
where case
      when (
              (select count(del_id)
               from vcd_deals
               where del_date=curdate()+1
                 and del_superSaver_deal=1)=0) then 1
      else 0
  end
order by del_date asc limit 3
```

I am getting the following error:

**Error**

> You can't specify target table 'vcd_deals' for update in FROM clause.

Actually I want to update first three rows of `vcd_deals` table only when 
`(select count(del_id) from vcd_deals where del_date=curdate()+1 and del_superSaver_deal=1)=0`.

please suggest is there any other way to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the problem with MySQL Parser. You can try `Inner Join` instead.

Otherwise you can enclose your subselect into a separate table like below:(not tested)

```
update vcd_deals
set del_date='2015-09-17'
where 0 = ( select Del_id_count 
             from (select count(del_id) as Del_id_count
                   from vcd_deals
                   where del_date=curdate()+1
                     and del_superSaver_deal=1) temp
                    )
order by del_date asc limit 3
```

Comment: It works thanks bro and i have one question why did you use two times select for finding `Del_id_count`

Comment: That is derived table which helps to improve performance. Look at the Links [Link1](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3914401/Use-Derived-Tables-in-Your-MySQL-Queries-to-Improve-Database-Performance.htm) ,[Link2](http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/subquery-vs-derived-table-944181.html) for more details

Comment: Hello @Crazy2crack can you please help me in another query .  i want to update two tables column with this query.

Comment: @Aabid : u mean two columns from two different tables? It will be better if you post a new question with sample data and expected output for better understanding.. At least if i'm not aware others can help u :)

Comment: i have posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583220/update-two-columns-of-two-different-table-in-single-query-with-order-by-and-limi

Answer (score 0):

You can try as per below-

```
UPDATE vcd_deals 
SET del_date='2015-09-17' 
WHERE del_date<>ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND del_superSaver_deal<>1 
ORDER BY del_date LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: but i want to update only when `select count(del_id) from vcd_deals where del_date=curdate()+1 and del_superSaver_deal=1` this query return 0

Comment: yes, means you want to exclude rows which satisfy given conditions...is update query is not doing same...